# boost: How to find the process id of a process by name?

Tags: c++, boost, process, terminate

I need a cross platform way to find a running process by name and get its process id. Then use boost's process library to terminate it.

Boost's process library requires process id to be known(http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/reference/classboost_1_1process_1_1process.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "process name"? The name of the executable program that gave origin to the process? What if there are more than one instance of that program, which one will you terminate? The only unique identifier for a process is its process id (aka PID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no such cross-platform facility.  The closest I know of is `pgrep` and that's a program, not a library, and it isn't part of Windows.

On Unix-like systems with procfs, you'll need to scan `/proc` to match however you want to.  I don't know how to do it on Windows, but I'm sure it's possible, and it can't be much worse than what you have to do on *nix.